# Incorrect rendering html template on hyperlink

Tags: hyperlink, underscore.js, templating

**Incorrect rendering html  with hyperlink data with spaces in Underscorejs Template.**

When I use hyperlink with spaces in json date on underscore template. It renders the html wrongly

Eg:
template:

```
<a href=<%-doclink%> target="_blank">,
```

data(json):

```
"doclink":"pdf/Consumerism SGO_Monthly Mailer_Apr 2015_v4.pdf",
```

Rendered html:

```
<a href="pdf/Consumerism" sgo_monthly="" mailer_apr="" 2015_v4.pdf="" target="_blank">
```

Please help to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Change your template to use quotes around the `href` attribute value:

```
<a href="<%-doclink%>" target="_blank">
```